# SPO default internal site missing settings

Tags: sharepoint-online, solution

We're using the default internal site on SharePoint Online. When going through the setting I'm missing the section for Web Designer Galleries specifically the Solution Gallery. Is there a way to enable this option on the default site?

Alternatively I can access the Solution Gallery by adding the direct path.

`https://SPO.sitecollection.com/_catalogs/solutions/Forms/AllItems.aspx`

The only issue I have with this is every time I try to upload a solution I get a message that pops up say I require access to the site, but I'm the Site Collection Administrator. When I send a request I go and approve my own request, but still no luck.

Is there a way for me to enable this setting on the default internal site or grant access to Solution Gallery?

Comment: It didn't work for me. I ran the command and get a "Set-SPOsite : The request uses too many resources." Can you help?

Comment: I would review you Server Resource Quota in the SharePoint admin center. See if you might need to increase the resources for your site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I end up getting this issue resolved. I had to enabled scripting capabilities.

I followed this [guide](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Turn-scripting-capabilities-on-and-off-1f2c515f-5d7e-448a-9fd7-835da935584f?ui=en-US&amp)

1. Sign in to Office 365
2. Go to the SharePoint admin center
3. select settings
4. Under Custom Script:
5. Change both options to "Allow users to run custom subscription on..."

It takes roughly 24 hours for the change to take effect on O365

I have found additional information what will speed up the process. [guide2](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_sharepoint-mso_win10-mso_o365b/getting-error-sorry-you-dont-have-access-to-this/9a76ffcb-25c1-462a-a001-64e358db8278?auth=1)

Proceeding from the steps above you will need to download the SharePoint Online Management Shell

Run the following commands below, replacing "contoso" with your company name.
Also the set-sposite command will point to the site collection you want to enable scrpting on.

1. Connect-SPOService -Url https://contoso-admin.sharepoint.com
2. set-sposite https://contoso.sharepoint.com -denyaddandcustomizepages 0

After the command has run, you should be able to access everything instantly.