# Solution Option is missing in Sharepoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, office-365, visual-web-part

I have created the trial site on Office 365.

I have created a Test Site in SharePoint Online.

Now I want to deploy custom web parts on SharePoint Online refer to the following link: https://collab365.community/sharepoint-online-2013-web-part-deployment/

The problem is I can not see "Solution" link under  Site Settings -> Solutions under Web Designer Galleries. Following is the snap shot

[image]

Kindly help

Comment: You can refer following link, that might helps you. [spo-default-internal-site-missing-settings](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/127852/spo-default-internal-site-missing-settings)

Comment: Developing Provider Hosted Apps proved as helpful for me for custom development

Answer (score 1):

[Sandbox solution](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office/blogs/removing-code-based-sandbox-solutions-in-sharepoint-online/)  deprecated already, you need either deploy [SharePoint add-in part](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/create-add-in-parts-to-install-with-your-sharepoint-add-in) or [SPFx solution](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/sharepoint-framework-overview).

Comment: Our organization is moving from SharePoint On Premises to SharePoint Online, so we want our visual web parts to be moved on SharePoint Online as it is. Please suggest a solution to add those web parts

Comment: Not support anymore, have to re-write with either above two solutions.

Comment: so The solution option can not be available now?

Comment: Yes, you're right.

Answer (score 1):

Sandbox solution deprecated long back.

If you want to migrate in SharePoint Classic view - You have below option:

Content editor web part( where you can refer your files)
SP hosted Apps. (SharePoint Hosted)
Provider Hosted Apps( you need a server to host , for example - Azure)
SharePoint Framework Apps( Client side Object Model)

If you are migrating in SharePoint Modern view - You have one option to deploy your code :
SharePoint Framework Apps( Client side Object Model)

To deploy your app model you must have set you app catalog in your tenant.